# Is there a ranking of the valuable flair of all combined Stack Exchange profiles?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues, rankings

Is there a ranking of the valuable flair of all combined Stack Exchange profiles? Like the one there is for each community but for all of them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none that I know of, however I've put together [the following SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/647117/top-network-users-by-combined-site-reputation) which lists the top users by total network reputation (for sites with > 200 rep as per flair rules) as well as showing where you are in the list (enter your network account ID, which you can get by going to https://stackexchange.com and viewing your profile, it's in the URL):

```sql
-- This query produces a top 100 list of users by combined network 
-- reputation across all sites, considering only sites where the user
-- has > 200 rep as per combined flair rules.
--
-- Enter your account ID in MyAccountID to see your rank as well.
--
-- I have no idea why it is so fast.

DECLARE @db SYSNAME
DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT Name 
  FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE database_id > 5
  AND (name NOT LIKE '%.Meta' OR name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
CREATE TABLE #users (AccountId int, DisplayName NVARCHAR(40), Reputation int);

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
  SET @q = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + ';'
    + 'INSERT INTO #users '
    + 'SELECT AccountId, DisplayName, Reputation '
    + 'FROM Users '
    + 'WHERE Reputation > 200'
  EXEC(@q)
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db
END;
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Reputation) DESC) Rank,
    MAX(DisplayName) PossibleDisplayName,
    SUM(Reputation) CombinedReputation, 
    COUNT(*) SiteCount,
    'https://stackexchange.com/users/' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(AccountId))) Profile, 
    AccountId
  FROM #users 
  GROUP BY AccountId) x
WHERE Rank <= 100 OR AccountId = ##MyAccountId##
ORDER BY CombinedReputation DESC
```

The current top 100 users as of March 19, 2017 (most recent SEDE update at the time of this writing) are:

```
Rank PossibleDisplayName    CombinedReputation SiteCount Profile                                 AccountId
---- ---------------------- ------------------ --------- --------------------------------------- --------- 
1    Jon Skeet              1021719            9         https://stackexchange.com/users/11683   11683     
2    Gilles                 781527             50        https://stackexchange.com/users/164368  164368    
3    Marc Gravell           752305             12        https://stackexchange.com/users/11975   11975     
4    Darin Dimitrov         723088             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/14332   14332     
5    BalusC                 719407             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/52822   52822     
6    VonC                   700009             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/4243    4243      
7    Uphill Luge            693730             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/9266    9266      
8    egreg                  680741             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/513966  513966    
9    Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams 678037             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/10930   10930     
10   Martijn Pieters        637347             8         https://stackexchange.com/users/35417   35417     
11   CommonsWare            630518             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/39846   39846     
12   Greg Hewgill           620774             22        https://stackexchange.com/users/680     680       
13   SLaks                  590098             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/15988   15988     
14   Nick Craver            559994             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/7598    7598      
15   Oded                   557285             11        https://stackexchange.com/users/1190    1190      
16   T.J. Crowder           540982             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/52616   52616     
17   Quentin                534394             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/10162   10162     
18   paxdiablo              531616             12        https://stackexchange.com/users/8291    8291      
19   Gordon Linoff          522389             2         https://stackexchange.com/users/1165580 1165580   
20   dasblinkenlight        508741             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/134022  134022    
21   Guffa                  507494             11        https://stackexchange.com/users/26521   26521     
22   Alex Martelli          506500             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/34048   34048     
23   Eric Lippert           505710             28        https://stackexchange.com/users/32093   32093     
24   Jonathan Leffler       487830             10        https://stackexchange.com/users/8423    8423      
25   marc_s                 484461             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/7633    7633      
26   CMS                    480798             2         https://stackexchange.com/users/3748    3748      
27   JaredPar               480306             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/11948   11948     
28   user26868              478941             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/24377   24377     
29   cletus                 466352             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/9867    9867      
30   BoltClock's a Unicorn  459705             8         https://stackexchange.com/users/37175   37175     
31   David Heffernan        454255             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/237126  237126    
32   Stephen C              439503             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/47283   47283     
33   JB Nizet               429764             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/277416  277416    
34   Brian M. Scott         428779             2         https://stackexchange.com/users/512076  512076    
35   Felix Kling            427761             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/76141   76141     
36   Shog9                  427097             14        https://stackexchange.com/users/620     620       
37   André Nicolas          425947             1         https://stackexchange.com/users/510889  510889    
38   Pascal Thivent         421458             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/26957   26957     
39   Gumbo                  420841             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/21746   21746     
40   Jerry Coffin           417432             22        https://stackexchange.com/users/60200   60200     
41   unutbu                 415363             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/64585   64585     
42   Reed Copsey            414495             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/25430   25430     
43   anubhava               412575             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/262968  262968    
44   user5341               409960             31        https://stackexchange.com/users/41067   41067     
45   Bozho                  408641             8         https://stackexchange.com/users/70258   70258     
46   Konrad Rudolph         407545             20        https://stackexchange.com/users/1475    1475      
47   tvanfosson             403852             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/7448    7448      
48   Bill the Lizard        403672             26        https://stackexchange.com/users/970     970       
49   bobince                403607             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/10108   10108     
50   Pekka 웃                403339             19        https://stackexchange.com/users/63368   63368     
51   Charles Bailey         403155             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/10375   10375     
52   Robert Harvey          390107             17        https://stackexchange.com/users/36137   36137     
53   Daniel Roseman         386112             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/36572   36572     
54   David Carlisle         380786             2         https://stackexchange.com/users/845543  845543    
55   Jeff Atwood            378372             28        https://stackexchange.com/users/1       1         
56   Peter Lawrey           375335             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/23121   23121     
57   Werner                 367500             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/514155  514155    
58   kennytm                360670             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/79153   79153     
59   Johannes Schaub - litb 359978             8         https://stackexchange.com/users/16029   16029     
60   Thomas Pornin          356963             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/92852   92852     
61   Michael Borgwardt      355152             29        https://stackexchange.com/users/9193    9193      
62   gbn                    350874             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/13638   13638     
63   Gonzalo Medina         343877             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/511178  511178    
64   Martin Smith           342298             10        https://stackexchange.com/users/27657   27657     
65   Joel Coel              335651             17        https://stackexchange.com/users/2212    2212      
66   deceze                 334400             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/378     378       
67   Mysticial              325536             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/559988  559988    
68   Aaron Bertrand         322323             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/24165   24165     
69   jfriend00              319793             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/432092  432092    
70   ChrisF                 319341             20        https://stackexchange.com/users/23619   23619     
71   S.Lott                 316448             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/6358    6358      
72   Jefromi                315728             14        https://stackexchange.com/users/41301   41301     
73   Barmar                 314617             8         https://stackexchange.com/users/1613587 1613587   
74   Paolo Bergantino       313173             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/8983    8983      
75   Kerrek SB              309329             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/293472  293472    
76   Qiaochu Yuan           308449             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/127441  127441    
77   xmm0                   308267             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/15778   15778     
78   nickf                  307995             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/5559    5559      
79   Bill Karwin            307346             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/10929   10929     
80   Erwin Brandstetter     305438             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/904738  904738    
81   Martin R               305384             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/1220712 1220712   
82   Quassnoi               304972             9         https://stackexchange.com/users/22397   22397     
83   Jörg W Mittag          303600             17        https://stackexchange.com/users/2172    2172      
84   Ladislav Mrnka         302954             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/180279  180279    
85   mu is too short        301287             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/221717  221717    
86   Dennis Williamson      299604             15        https://stackexchange.com/users/13225   13225     
87   Daniel Fischer         299449             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/996105  996105    
88   Oli                    294902             17        https://stackexchange.com/users/7412    7412      
89   Tim Schmelter          292502             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/106749  106749    
90   skaffman               291712             4         https://stackexchange.com/users/11089   11089     
91   Jon                    289395             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/20816   20816     
92   Pascal MARTIN          288556             7         https://stackexchange.com/users/46833   46833     
93   alex                   283846             6         https://stackexchange.com/users/15143   15143     
94   Marc B                 282534             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/40721   40721     
95   Arun P Johny           282390             3         https://stackexchange.com/users/39580   39580     
96   BoundaryImposition     280144             18        https://stackexchange.com/users/270599  270599    
97   NPE                    279359             11        https://stackexchange.com/users/152622  152622    
98   user22644              273961             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/80529   80529     
99   Valorum                271524             13        https://stackexchange.com/users/3776439 3776439   
100  unwind                 271292             5         https://stackexchange.com/users/13903   13903
```

If you view the above table through the SEDE link instead, the profile links will be clickable. Flair images can be accessed at `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/###.png` where `###` is the account ID.

Also [here is a version of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/647136/top-network-users-by-combined-site-reputation-excluding-so) that excludes Stack Overflow (all languages), if you are curious.

I could probably add a column containing a list of site names like the flair does, but TSQL has no `GROUP_CONCAT` and so it's more complicated than I can think about at the moment. The query is already pretty weird.

Comment: As an aside: Does anybody know why that query is so fast? I don't mean the caching, it was < 1 second the first time I ran it. It was *suspiciously* fast.

Comment: Can an external website link this query results? is it allowed?

Comment: @Pablo I don't see why it would be a problem. If you link directly to the query URL the results will be there in the Results tab. SEDE caches queries so it won't put any real load on the DB to keep querying the page. You may want to make a modified version of the query that excludes the account ID parameter field (just drop the `OR` condition out of that final `WHERE`), so that folks can just run it without having to type anything in.