# How can I query for StackExchange.* databases on the Data SE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

By default my table names are using the current site to which I am connected on. Thus a query `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Users` will list 100 users.

If I wish to select from a different database, in some cases I can use query like

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM superuser.dbo.Users;
```

As I can see, this short name is possible only for sites with a different name as `*.stackexchange.com`. (The "trinity", for example and some other.)

How can I query, for example, from tables in the Physics SE?

I've got the list of the database names with a `SELECT * FROM sysdatabases`, but I couldn't go further. Any tries to name them as `StackExchange.dbo.devops.users`, `StackExchange.devops.dbo.users` and similar were all unsuccessful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database names contain literal periods, so you have to escape them, e.g.:

```
SELECT TOP 100
  *
FROM
  [StackExchange.Devops].dbo.Users
```

---

For example (contrived), [this lists the top users on DevOps who also have SO/SU accounts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/649941) and provides a total rep for the three sites:

```
SELECT TOP 50
  CONCAT('https://stackexchange.com/users/', so.AccountId) Network_Profile,
  dv.DisplayName DevOps_UserName,
  so.Reputation SO_Rep,
  su.Reputation SU_Rep,
  dv.Reputation DevOps_Rep,
  so.Reputation + su.Reputation + dv.Reputation Total
FROM
  StackOverflow.dbo.Users so
  INNER JOIN SuperUser.dbo.Users su ON su.AccountId = so.AccountId
  -- must escape db name:
  INNER JOIN [StackExchange.Devops].dbo.Users dv ON dv.AccountId = so.AccountId
ORDER BY
  DevOps_Rep DESC
```

It doesn't matter which site you have selected in SEDE when you run that.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `USE` statement, and all subsequent queries will be on that database. Same escaping rules apply. For example, [this displays the number of up and downvotes on the currently selected site (which is Mechanics), Worldbuilding, and DevOps](https://data.stackexchange.com/mechanics/query/649950):

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE (SiteName nvarchar(32), UpVotes int, DownVotes int)

-- This first one uses the currently selected site:
INSERT INTO @Example SELECT DB_NAME(),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
  FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId IN(2, 3);

USE [StackExchange.Worldbuilding];
INSERT INTO @Example SELECT DB_NAME(),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
  FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId IN(2, 3);

USE [StackExchange.DevOps];
INSERT INTO @Example SELECT DB_NAME(),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
  FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId IN(2, 3);

SELECT * FROM @Example
```

That could save you typing in certain cases.

Comment: Don't forget you can build up a sql statement for all databases to do some networkwide query-ing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286532/158100

Comment: In addition to @rene's example, here is another approach with cursors and a temporary table: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292834/230261