# Is it possible to query multiple sites in one data SE query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was curious about finding users that have higher reputation on SE sites other than stackoverflow.

I'm kind of fuzzy on what I want to do, but my hypothesis is that ... people who are involved in SE but not very involved in SO are rare.

So anyway, I went to https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new and immediately realized that I need to limit my query to a single site.

Question(s):

a) Is it possible to query multiple sites in some way that I've overlooked?
b) If not, is this feature planned?
c) If not, then out of interest, what is missing for it to be implemented?

thanks!

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: [Directly support cross-site queries in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148268/300411).  Also, [Allow cross-site queries in data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83570/300411).

Comment: Plenty of examples of the cursor technique; e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293300/230261. Also if you want to query from specific databases see examples at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293027/230261 (and the comments under there have links to other automatic cross-site techniques).

Comment: Btw as for your b/c) -- not sure what you mean. Every site has its own database, so you have to use standard cross-database techniques to query from more than one db at a time. So I guess what's missing is uh... a complete redesign of MS SQL Server, a reimagination of the concept of databases as distinct sources of data, and the subsequent general paradigm shift across the entire world of SQL and database design. Either that or SE merely has to redo the fundamental database layout for the whole network and combine every site into one, single, giant database. Either way, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: The linked question has exactly what I meant. Thanks.