# Writing a query for multiple communities at once

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is is possible in SEDE to write a query targeting many communities simultaneously?

I've seen this [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136352/how-can-i-search-multiple-sites-for-my-posts-about-a-nix-question-at-once) but it doesn't help me. e.g. I would like to see how many questions were asked in X, Y, and Z communities in the past 6 months.

Comment: Or if you don't want to automate a network-wide query and you know X,Y,Z exactly, you can use their full database names, e.g. `select * from [StackExchange.Aviation].dbo.Users`. Do `select * from sys.databases` to see a list of db names and [don't forget to escape them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292994/how-can-i-query-for-stackexchange-databases-on-the-data-se/293027#293027).